# How to retrieve substring data from same table but different field/column in cake php

Tags: php, sql-server, cakephp

How to retrieve substring data from same table but different field/column in cake php?

I have a column named `RAS_Code` which contains code e.g `L01-0-00-00-000`, so I need a new column named `Line` which contain the substring data from `RAS_Code` e.g `L01`.

I want to retrieve `RAS_Code` substring data to become my `Line` data. Here is my code, I'm not sure where is the mistake. Please help,thanks a lot!

```
$this->Upload->Line;
$this->Upload->create();
$this->Upload->Line->recursive = -1;
$column = $this->Upload->find('all', array('fields' => array('Upload.RAS_Code')));

$line = substr($column, 0, -12);
$column = $line;
$this->Upload->save($this->request->data, array('validate' => true));
```

Answer (score 0):

first `$column` is an array not a string. You have to loop trough all the records and set the correct value for line

second: if you want just the first 3 characters of the string, your code will return `-0-00-00-000` and not `L01`

third: it's not clear what do you want to do with this data. DO you want to update your table? So why don't you just run an update query

anyway to answer your question:

```
foreach($column as $index => $row)
{
    $column[$index]['Upload']['line'] = substr($row['Upload']['RAS_Code'], 0, 3));
}
```

**edit**

It seems that you just need to perform an update. I assume that you already created a `line` column in your table. If so simply do:

```
$this->Upload->updateAll(array('line' => 'LEFT(RAS_Code, 3'));
```

Comment: thank you for the comment! i'm doing an upload process, upload csv file to the database. So, when each batch of CSV file uploaded i want to add a Line column and it will retrieve the uploaded RAS_Code column data.